# Removing empty lines in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

How can I replace empty lines in Notepad++? I tried a find and replace with the empty lines in the find, and nothing in the replace, but it did not work; it probably needs regex.

Answer (score 441, accepted):

You need something like a regular expression.

**You have to be in `Extended` mode**

If you want all the lines to end up on a **single line** use `\r\n`. If you want to simply remove **empty** lines, use `\n\r` as @Link originally suggested.

Replace either expression with nothing.

Comment: Should first select 'extended` in search mode.

Comment: It should be noted that replacing all on `\r\n\r\n` can cause 2 of your lines to be joined together. `23` Text on line 23!`\r\n` `24 \r\n` `25\r\n` `26`Line 26 text.`r\n` can be compressed to `23` Text on line 23!Line 26 text.

Comment: To get your lines not to be joined together you have to search for `\r\n\r\n` and replace with `\r\n`.

Comment: See @BoltClock's comment below. Also, if your file is saved with Unix line endings, you can convert it to Windows line endings in Edit > EOL Conversion > Windows Format before doing the find and replace.

Comment: If you wish to remove lines with only spaces and tabs or nothing try using regex replace to match `\r\n\W*\r\n` and replace with `\r\n`

Comment: @Myster First thing to say I barely know regex, so apologize if I'm wrong. I think your suggestion wouldn't do the trick with many empty lines in a row, have you tested it and does it really works?

Comment: @ST3 hmm what was I thinking, This one is much better: `(\r\n|\r|\n)(\s*(\r\n|\r|\n))+` and replace with `\r\n` see it in action here: https://regex101.com/r/qD9dB1/1

Comment: What on earth are you talking about when you say \n\r  you do realise you have that backwards don't you?

Comment: @barlop, `\n\r` is for removing completely empty lines. for example `line 1\r\n\r\nline 3`: removing \n\r will leave you with `line 1\r\nline 3`

Answer (score 642):

There is now a built-in way to do this as of version 6.5.2

`Edit -> Line Operations -> Remove Empty Lines` or `Remove Empty Lines (Containing Blank characters)`

[image: Screenshot of removing empty lines]

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't consider your selection, it will delete all the empty lines in the file even if you have selected only some of them.

Comment: If this is a one-time operation, you can extract the selected lines to the new notepad++ tab and perform that operation there. Copy-paste procedure for 5seconds. Any other workaround that cannot be accomplished in that time is a waste in my opinion. But if you are doing that every day 100 times...

Comment: I was using this (even assigned my shortcut), but it's a lot slower than option above, so use smartly...

Answer (score 123):

There is a plugin that adds a menu entitled `TextFX`.  This menu, which houses a dizzying array of quick text editing options, gives a person the ability to make quick coding changes.  In this menu, you can find selections such as Drop Quotes, Delete Blank Lines as well as Unwrap and Rewrap Text

**Do the following:**

```
TextFX > TextFX Edit > Delete Blank Lines
TextFX > TextFX Edit > Delete Surplus Blank Lines
```

Comment: Not sure as of when, but it would seem that this plugin is installed by default now. Slightly off-topic, but one of the other incredibly useful features, under `TextFX > TextFX Tools`, is line sorting, optionally removing duplicates. Very handy way of doing a Unix `sort -u` on a Windows box without cygwin or unxutils or similar.

Comment: [Here's a link to the TextFx Plugin.](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/TextFX/)  I found it very useful. 
Use:
    `Settings > Import > plugin...`
and find the dll file to install it. It becomes a menu item by `Plugins`

Comment: will this work on all open documents, or one document at a time?

Answer (score 107):

1. notepad++
2. Ctrl-H
3. Select Regular Expression
4. Enter `^[ \t]*$\r?\n` into find what, leave replace empty. This will match all lines starting with white space and ending with carriage return (in this case a windows crlf)
5. Click the Find Next button to see for yourself how it matches only empty lines.

Comment: I had to use this method instead of some of the other methods to get it to easily work in a macro.  Thank you.

Comment: even shorter and also lesser replacements needed because of multiple empty lines will be replaced at once: ^\s*$\r?\n

Comment: In notepad++ i used `(^[ \t]*$\s)\s*` in the find box and left replace empty. Works great. Thanks!

Comment: why does `^\s*$` work for multiple lines? shouldn't ^$ "restrict" it to one line? (@njank  or anyone else)

Comment: Thanks for this regex expression, it worked well, but it took a while to complete execution.

Comment: @albin, this pattern is matching a (possibly blank) line followed by a (possible single carriage return and) newline. It's the combination of "more than one blank line" that gives it so much power. I used the suggestion from njank and specified Replace with \n -- this replaced multiple blank lines with a single blank line.

Answer (score 43):

1. Press **ctrl + h** (Shortcut for replace).
2. In the **Find what** zone, type `^\R` ( for exact empty lines) or `^\h*\R` ( for empty lines with blanks, only).
3. Leave the **Replace with** zone **empty**.
4. Check the **Wrap around** option.
5. Select the **Regular expression** search mode.
6. Click on the **Replace All** button.

[image]

Comment: This worked for me without any issues or additional settings to change. Thanks!

Comment: Except that it's shorter, what exactly is the difference to [SleepyBoBos's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14064039/2089396)?

Comment: @Albin, different regex:
SleepyBoBos:
 ^[ \t]*$\r?\n This will match all lines starting with white space and ending with carriage return (in this case a windows crlf)
My version:
^\R ( for exact empty lines) or ^\h*\R ( for empty lines with blanks, only).

Comment: @Alex.K. that I understood, since it's already mentioned in the answers themselves. Sorry, should have been more specific: is there anything else in the white space but space and tab in `\h`? Also `\r?\n` already includes Win and Unix line breaks, whats the advantage of using `\R`? Are there "regular" use cases where you need it?

Answer (score 27):

You can follow the technique as shown in the following screenshot:

- **Find what:** `^\r\n`
- **Replace with:** `keep this empty`
- **Search Mode:** `Regular expression`
- **Wrap around:** selected

[image]

**NOTE:** for *nix files just find by `\n`

Comment: works well (note: not for lines that includes any non-print characters like space or tab)

Comment: Loved it! This should have been the accepted answer.

Answer (score 20):

This worked for me:

1. Press `ctrl + h` (Shortcut for replace)
2. Write one of the following regex in `find what` box.
   `[\n\r]+$` or `^[\n\r]+`
3. Leave `Replace with` box blank
4. In `Search Mode`, select `Regex`
5. Click on `Replace All`
   Done!

Comment: This is the only solution that did not screw up my huge .csv files. Thanks!

Comment: plus one because I finally know the shortcut for replace :-D

Answer (score 17):

1) `Ctrl + H` ( Or `Search  Replace..`) to open Replace window.

2) Select `'Search Mode'` **'Regular expression'**

3) In **'Find What'** type `^(\s*)(.*)(\s*)$` & in **'Replace With'** type `\2`

- `^` - Matches start of line character
- `(\s*)` - Matches empty space characters
- `(.*)` - Matches any characters
- `(\s*)` - Matches empty spaces characters
- `$` - Matches end of line character
- `\2` - Denotes the matching contend of the 2nd bracket

[image]
Refer  https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html for more on regex.

Comment: Please note: This does not only replace empty lines, it replaces e.g. indents (tab and space) as well

Comment: This was the first answer on this list that actually removed empty top and bottom lines. Great answer

Answer (score 15):

In notepad++ press CTRL+H , in search mode click on the "Extended (\n, \r, \t ...)" radio button then type in the "Find what" box: \r\n (short for CR LF) and leave the "Replace with" box empty..

Finally hit replace all

Comment: actually, I tried it, see my clarification in my answer. *You were on to something!*

Comment: This assumes the line endings are Windows (CRLF) though, if your file is saved with Unix line endings search only for `\n`.

Comment: @Brad: I wrote in between the () "short for CR LF", didn't want codetrek to think \n is CR, hence the edit.

Comment: Wrong answer, puts all lines in one line.

Answer (score 13):

Well I'm not sure about the regex or your situation..

How about CTRL+A, Select the TextFX menu -> TextFX Edit -> Delete Blank Lines and viola all blank line gone.

A side note - if the line is blank i.e. does not contain spaces, this will work

Answer (score 13):

You can search for the following regex: `^(?:[\t ]*(?:\r?\n|\r))+` and replace it with empty field

Answer (score 11):

Ctrl+H.

find - \r\r
replace with - \r.

Comment: This works for me, removing extra line, in the sense of finding double \r replace with single \r. Thanks!!

Comment: This worked well, however I found that I needed to run it several times in my document before all instances of \r\r were gone. I'm unsure why.

Answer (score 7):

This obviously does not work if the blank lines contain tabs or blanks. Many web pages (e.g. http://www.guardian.co.uk/) contain these white lines, as a result of a faulty HTML editor.

Remove white space using regular expression as follows:

> change pattern: [\t ]+$
>   into nothing.

where [\t ] matches either tab or space. '+' matches one or more occurrences, and '$' marks the end of line.

Then use notepad++/textFX to remove single or extra empty lines.
Be sure that these blank lines are not significant in the given context.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Sometimes \n\r etc not work, here to figure it out, what your actually regular expression should be.

Advantage of this trick: If you want to replace in multiple file at once, you must need this method. Above will not work...

Answer (score 4):

1. Edit >> Blank Operations >> Trim Leading and Trailing Spaces (to remove black tabs and spaces in empty lines)
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to get replace window and replace pattern: `^\r\n` with nothing (select regular expression)

**Note:** step 1 will remove your code intendation done via tabs and blank spaces

Answer (score 4):

CTRL+A, Select the TextFX menu -> TextFX Edit -> Delete Blank Lines as suggested above works.

But if lines contains some space, then move the cursor to that line and do a CTRL + H. The "Find what:" sec will show the blank space and in the "Replace with" section, leave it blank.
Now all the spaces are removed and now try CTRL+A, Select the TextFX menu -> TextFX Edit -> Delete Blank Lines

Answer (score 4):

`/n/r` assumes a specific type of line break. To target any blank line you could also use:

```
^$
```

This says - any line that begins and then ends with nothing between. This is more of a catch-all. Replace with the same empty string.

Answer (score 3):

I did not see the combined one as answer, so search for ^\s+$ and replace by {nothing}

```
^\s+$ means
  ^ start of line
  \s+ Matches minimum one whitespace character (spaces, tabs, line breaks)
  $ until end of line
```

Comment: if you want multiple lines you can try: `^\s+^(\S)` and replace with `\1`.

Answer (score 3):

This pattern is tested in Notepad++ v8.1.1

It replaces all `spaces/tabs/blank lines` before and after each row of text.

It shouldn't mess with anything in the middle of the text.

```
Find: ^(\s|\t)+|(\s|\t)+$

Replace: leave this blank


Before:
_____________________________________
\tWORD\r\n
\r\n
\tWORD\s\tWORD\s\t\r\n
\r\n
\r\n
WORD\s\s\tWORD\t\sWORD\s\r\n 
\t\r\n
\s\s\s\r\n
WORD\s\sWORD\s\s\t\r\n

____________________________________


After:
_____________________________________
WORD\r\n
WORD\s\tWORD\r\n
WORD\s\s\tWORD\t\sWORD\r\n
WORD\s\sWORD
_____________________________________
```

Answer (score 2):

A few of the above expressions and extended expressions did not work for me, but the regular expression "$\n$" did.

Answer (score 1):

An easy alternative for removing white space from empty lines:

1. TextFX>TextFX Edit> Trim Trailing Spaces

This will remove all trailing spaces, including trailing spaces in blank lines.
Make sure, no trailing spaces are significant.

Answer (score 1):

this work for me:

```
SEARCH:^\r  
REPLACE:            (empty)
```

Comment: This will not work for linux eol `\n` and windows eol `\r\n`