# Remove 3 blank lines and two lines with text below them in Notepad++

Tags: regex, t-sql, notepad++

I ran a sql script that uses a cursor to execute `sp_table_privileges` on each table in a database.

If you run the script and save the output to a file you get this after each iteration:

```
data,data,data,data,data,data,data

(x row(s) affected)

next_table_name
TABLE_QUALIFIER,TABLE_OWNER,TABLE_NAME,GRANTOR,GRANTEE,PRIVILEGE,IS_GRANTABLE
```

I was able to remove the `(x row(s) affected)` in Notepad++ by using the regular expression replace with `(\(.*\))` but it replaced it with a blank line.

So now I have 3 blank lines, the next tables name and the columns.

I know you can [remove blank lines in Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866034/removing-empty-lines-in-notepad).

But, can I use a regular expression to find 3 blank lines, remove them and two lines below them?

If not is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correcly.
Find

```
(\r\n){4}.*\r\n.*
```

replace with (Replace All)

```
leave empty
```

Box ".matches newline" leave unchecked

And if you want to delete everything beneath the three empty lines find

```
(\r\n){3}.*
```

replace with (Replace All)

```
leave empty
```

In this case Box ".matches newline" has to be checked

Comment: That works like a charm on my example, I think you answered correctly. +1

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify : 
So you get something like in my screenshot once you applied your regular expression ? correct ? And then you delete the 3 blank lines like I do here ?

[image]

And you get :

```
> data,data,data,data,data,data,data 
> next_table_name
> TABLE_QUALIFIER,TABLE_OWNER,TABLE_NAME,GRANTOR,GRANTEE,PRIVILEGE,IS_GRANTABLE
```

And now you want to remove "next.." and "TABLE_QUALIFIER"...etc automatically so you just keep the data,data,data etc ?

[Editing with Placido's solution for the Author of the question]

Have a look, that's what you wanted, correct ?

[image]

And then :

[image]

Comment: Yes...I want to get rid of 'next_table_name' and the line after it: TABLE_QUALIFIER, ...    Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, have a look at Placido's solution.