# Removing empty lines with notepad++ causes T_Variable Syntax Error

Tags: php, syntax, syntax-error, notepad++

[Removing empty lines in Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866034/removing-empty-lines-in-notepad)

As described in the thread above you are able to remove empty lines with notepad++. I did try those methods but I am always receiving weird T_Variable Syntax Errors (mostly in line 1-6). There definitely is no error in those lines and I can not see one anywhere.

It also happens when I manually delete the empty lines in some areas of the code (first 5 lines for example). I am guessing this is an encoding problem but also reencoding in UTF-8, Ascii etc. did not help.

Those lines were added when I used an online editor from a webhoster a couple of months ago (1 empty line between the lines that were there before).

I do not get it, maybe you do (thanks in advance!). The file is at http://lightningsoul.com/index.php

And here is the first block of code:

```
<?php

 include("db/lg_db_login.php"); 
//require 'fb/facebook.php';
 if (isset($_GET['c'])) { $content = $_GET['c']; }
 else { $content = ""; } 
 if (isset($_GET['sc'])) { $subcontent = $_GET['sc']; }
 else { $subcontent = ""; }
 if (isset($_GET['setlang'])) { $setlang = $_GET['setlang']; }
 else { $setlang = "eng"; } 
 $cat = $_GET['cat'];

// Check if Lightningsoul.de or .com
 $findme   = '.de';
 $posde = strpos($thisurl, $findme);

// Note our use of ===.  Simply == would not work as expected
// because the position of 'a' was the 0th (first) character.
if ($posde === false) {
    $lang = "en";
} else {
    $lang = "de";
}
 include("db/pageturn_class.php"); 

$findStr   = '/lightningsoulcom';
$isApp = strpos($thisurl, $findStr);

// Beachten Sie die Verwendung von ===. Ein einfacher Vergleich (==) liefert
// nicht das erwartete Ergebnis, da die Position von 'a' die nullte Stelle
// (also das erste Zeichen) ist
/*if ($isApp == false) {
    $getStyle = "css/get_style.php";
} else {
   $getStyle = "css/get_style_small.php";
} */
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

[image: Code looks like this]

Comment: First of all, why do you want to remove empty line ? In wich part of your code ? If it is in `<?php ?>` it's not necessary. Removing empty lines is usefull (relativly...) tu make your html output lighter. The php part is never rendered on HTML, si it doesn't matter if there is emply lines, it's just easier for developer to read.

Comment: Apart from the advice above. "Do not remove empty lines. Readability of your code is TOP priority!" did you check the modifed file? What does it look like?

Comment: http://lightningsoul.com/private/img/empty_lines.png Because the code looks like this. There is ANOTHER empty line between the normal empty lines that make the code readable. Maybe you should have read what I have written in the original post?!

Comment: ToBe: What modified file? I removed the lines and of course I checked it. It looks like the code I gave you.

Comment: The code you have shown, without additional blank lines, shows _no syntax errors whatsoever_ when just copy&paste-d and executed.

Comment: And the “encoding problem” is not on the level of the character set – the online editor you used most likely simply was not able to properly work with the different _line break_ formats used across different OS and therefor duplicated them …

Comment: Well it somehow fixed itself (have no clue why). But I have still a very weird behaviour in the fb og debugger:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Flightningsoul.de%2F%3Fc%3Dmedia%26sc%3Dvid%26cat%3Dgaming%26id%3D190
It says there is no og:title when clearly there is one for example ...?!

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Flightningsoul.de%2F%3Fc%3Dmedia%26sc%3Dvid%26cat%3Dgaming%26id%3D190
This is what facebook sees. This is NOT AT ALL what I am seeing when I look at the source code in IE / FF. There is no <head> tag on the fb version, for example?! What the freak is going on...???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in line 181 where something (notepad++?!) must have changed

```
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

to

```
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=Windows-1250" />
```

That produced lots of errors as one would expect. I only found it by removing the head part by part.