# Notepad++ delete all text except URL

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have multiple files with text like ...

```
<studio>Morabito Picture Company</studio>
<trailer>plugin://plugin.video.youtube/?action=play_video&amp;videoid=QFbC5XGMOvI</trailer>
<dateadded>2016-10-16 22:25:51</dateadded>
```

I would like to remove anything except the URL **between** `<trailer>` and `</trailer>`.

How is this possible in Notepad++ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the replace function (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) in Notepad++ and a regular expression like this:

```
.*<trailer>(.+)</trailer>.*
```

The parentheses catch whatever is stored in between them in variable `\1`. Just type `\1` in the "replace with:" field and make sure that you have selected the ". matches newlines" alternative.

It is also possible to apply this to all files in a directory by using the Find in Files function (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) clicking the button "Replace in Files". Be cautious though as to not change any data unintentionally.

Answer (score 0):

Using Replace in Notepad++ with Ctr+H or Menu->Search->Replace, where you tick Regular expression.

1. Remove all other tags with content between opening and closing tag, with the following line:

   <(?!trailer).*>.*?</(?!trailer).*> in Find what and nothing in Replace With field and click Replace All.
2. Replace<trailer>url</trailer> with url. Write:

   <trailer>(.*?)</trailer>

in Find what field
and

```
$1
```

in Replace With field. Click Replace All.

Edit: To get rid of the redundant empty lines use:

```
[\n\r]+$
```

in Find what and nothing in Replace With and click Replace All. This is from: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866034/removing-empty-lines-in-notepad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866034/removing-empty-lines-in-notepadhttp://)