# R RegEx gsub() Equivalent of "Line Operations>Remove Empty Lines (Containing Blank Characters)" in CSV file

Tags: r, regex, csv, gsub

I have a CSV fwith several columns: Tweet, date, etc. The spaces in some Tweets is causing blank lines and undesired truncated lines.

What works:
1. Using Notepad++'s function "Line Operations>Remove Empty Lines (Containing Blank Characters)" 
2. Search and replace: `\r` with nothing.

However, I need to do this for a large number of files, and **I can't manage to find a Regular Expression with gsub() in R that will do what the Notepadd++ function does.**

Note that replacing `^[ \t]*$\r?\n` with nothing and then `\r` with nothing does work in Notepad++, but not in R, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866034/removing-empty-lines-in-notepad), but it does not work with g(sub) in R.

I have tried the following code:

`tx  <- readLines("tweets.csv")
subbed <-gsub(pattern = "^[ \\t]*$\\r?\\n", replace = "", x = tx)
subbed <-gsub(pattern = "\r", replace = "", x = subbed)
writeLines(subbed, "output.csv")`

This is the input:

[image: Problems caused by spacing in Tweets]

This is the desired output:

[image: Desired output]

Comment: Maybe `grep("^\\s*$", tx, invert=TRUE, value=TRUE)`?

Comment: Or, `grep("^\\w{3} \\w{3} \\d{2} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}", tx, value=TRUE)`

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew the first one just deletes everything; the second one does work, but a lot of lines are truncated and the first row (col names) is deleted.

Comment: What are your column names? Also, `grep` cannot truncate the lines, it either returns a matched line or not.

Comment: I think you are just printing long lines in the console and they are only truncated there for better viewing, they are not really truncated.

Comment: No, I mean that they are actually truncated in the output file, not in the console.
Headers are:
`"created_at";"id_str";"text";"in_reply_to_status_id";"username1";"userscreen_name1";"userlocation1";"userurl1";"userdescription1";"mediaurl"`

Comment: I have tested and they are not truncated in any way. If yours are, please share the sample of the real file. Images never help when you deal with regex/patterns.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
library(readtext)
tx <- readtext("weets.csv")
subbed <- gsub("(?m)^\\h*\\R?", "", tx$text, perl=TRUE)
subbed <- gsub("\r", "", subbed, fixed=TRUE)
writeLines(trimws(subbed), "output.csv")
```

The `readtext` llibrary reads the file into a single variable and thus all line break chars are kept.

Comment: Thanks. The headers are there now, but there are still incomplete lines.

I illustrate with some screen caps:

Original [link] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xFSWDnl1A8EMWf4jK2PIAVtRSAF2aY5c/view?usp=sharing)

Manual editing output: [link] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_dW8IvHdB9jvrPHnrS_kYJvGAOX9IYmM/view?usp=sharing)

Output with this code: (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EUTK7DSbgNXE72MVkbkwzWnogQDu2qYB/view?usp=sharing)
E.g. lines 24, 35 are incomplete.

Comment: @linguist_at_large Ok, so you mean you need to read the file in a single variable, remove all blank lines and then remove CR symbols?

Comment: @linguist_at_large What are the linebreaks in the file? CRLF between lines and CR inside lines? What is the encoding?

Comment: I would just like to find the right regex so the output looks like the one I got by editing it manually with the method described above with Notepad++ (Remove Empty Lines (Containing Blank Characters) and then delete CRs"

Comment: @linguist_at_large It is not a matter of a regex because `readlines` read in *lines* and you need to read in the whole file into a single  variable.

Comment: @linguist_at_large If it still does not work, you must share the file / part of the file you are working with. No images.