# How to quickly delete all empty comment lines and empty javadoc lines?

Tags: java

I want to find a solution to quickly delete all empty comment lines and empty javadoc lines in all my java files, as shown below:

```
/**
 * getBuildTime
 *
 *
 * @return
 */
//
//get build time
public Date getBuildTime () {
    return buildTime;
}
```

The result I want returns:

```
 /**
 * getBuildTime
 * @return
 */
//get build time
public Date getBuildTime () {
    return buildTime;
}
```

Thanks and would appreciate any solution you offer!

Comment: Using `sed` would work quite quickly. If you use a IDE supporting regex you can search and remove all lines matching `^\s*\*\s*$`

Comment: @federico-klez-culloca I am using eclipse and notepad ++ on windows at the same time, however, eclipse cannot replace all my files at once (it is scattered in subfolders), sed seems only available in Linux .

Comment: Notepad++'s "Find in files" with the sub-folder flag checked seems like the best option then.

Comment: Also, see [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876296/regex-remove-lines-containing-help-etc) about removing matching lines.

Comment: Thank you, I tried `^\s*\*\s*$` on eclipse. However, the result I received was that empty javadoc lines were removed but left empty lines, it did not remove empty lines after removing empty lines of javadoc.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I then suggested you do that with notepad++, combining the regex with the question I linked.

Comment: Thank you, I used it in conjunction with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51041118/9742353), everything has been solved!